# Can't access certain objects from array even though they do exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

Even though my array is filled with 7 objects I can only access 4 of them, when I try to access the 5th one I get undefined for some reason.

[image: snapshot from the console log]

now you can already see the [Array(4) even though its actual amount of objects is 7, the objects that i can acces look like this:

```
Object$$hashKey"object:8
"briefDescription:"09. value"
city:null
date:null
id:"1ca260e4-9e47-4366-9f53-5e7a7ebad956"
managerAction:undefined
name:"SCA 1704 01696"
number:"2017-07-24T14:01:00+0000"
street:"waiting"
type:"change"
```

and the ones that are not accesible for some reason are like this:

```
$$hashKey:"object:20
"briefDescription:"value"
city:"Woonboulevard 10 "
date:"ALMELO "
id:"3e9485c1-0c7e-4e55-b1aa-9707cba78766"
managerAction:undefined
name:"SI 1704 07644"
number:"2017-07-17T14:11:00.000+0000"
street:"In progress"
type:"incident"
```

the only difference is their type which is either an incident or change.

now for my actual code: [image]

which in the end results in the following (snap from console):
[image]

How can I access the objects that are currently not accessible? 
(if I need to post more code as to how I get the data being checked please do tell)

Comment: Your getChanges function seems to have a few typos in it: menu.Lijst and data.lenght.

Comment: looks like you have an array within an array?

Comment: correct, that should not matter in this instance however because i can access the first 4(so 0-1-2-3) just fine

Comment: Where in your code do you end up with an array of 7 elements? I don't see that reflected in your console snapshot either.

Comment: console.log(array,"the array") last snapshot the expanded array.

Comment: Also, as for that black rectangle part. The array has length 4 so the last item in the array would be at `[0][3]` not `[0][4]`

Comment: So what I think is happening is that at the time the console logs the array it only has a length of 4, but when you go into the console and open it, the contents of the array has already changed by that point, so the console gets the updated array rather than a "snapshot" of the array. If that makes sense.

Comment: but that is the whole weird part right, above it its clearly shown the actual length is 7 objects so [0][4] should exist, i can however only acces 0-1-2-3 from the code

Comment: I would recommend you include your code here instead of screenshots.